# Import Xml File and Bind to Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, xml-deserialization

I would like to import an xml file and deserialize it into my model objects.

I am using C# MVC4 Asp.Net 4.51

I have tried a number of methods - if someone can provide some guidance on the best way to achieve this it would be appreciated.

I have tried but cannot get this to work:

```
 public static KronosPunchRoundRuleSummary Deserialize()
 {
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(KronosPunchRoundRuleSummary));
     TextReader textReader;

     textReader = new StreamReader(@"c:\WSAPunchRoundRule.xml");

     KronosPunchRoundRuleSummary summary = (KronosPunchRoundRuleSummary)serializer.Deserialize(textReader); 
     textReader.Close();
 }
```

I have also tried this`enter code here` but I get an error saying it does not expect Kronos_WFC xmlns:

```
public static KronosPunchRoundRuleSummary Deserialize()
 {
     //XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(KronosPunchRoundRuleSummary));
     //TextReader textReader;

 //textReader = new StreamReader(@"c:\WSAPunchRoundRule.xml");

 //KronosPunchRoundRuleSummary summary = (KronosPunchRoundRuleSummary)serializer.Deserialize(textReader); 
 //textReader.Close();

 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load(@"c:\WSAPunchRoundRule.xml");
 string xmlcontents = doc.InnerXml;


 return null;
```

}

The xml file looks like this

```
`<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<Kronos_WFC TimeStamp="03/12/2013 14:59 GMT+04:00" WFCVersion="6.2.11.231" VERSION="1.0">


-<Response action="RetrieveAllForUpdate" Status="Success">

<WSAPunchRoundRule OutPunchLateChangePoint="0:00" UnscheduledInGrace="0:00" OutPunchEarlyInsideRound="0:01" OutPunchEarlyOutsideGrace="0:00" Name="Default Early Start" OutPunchEarlyOutsideRound="0:01" UseScheduledOut="false" InPunchLateInsideGrace="0:00" InPunchLateInsideRound="0:01" OutPunchLateOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchEarlyInsideGrace="0:00" UnscheduledInRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyChangePoint="2:00" InPunchLateOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchLateOutsideRound="0:01" OutPunchLateInsideGrace="0:00" IsMissedOutException="true" TransferGrace="0:00" UnscheduledOutGrace="0:00" TransferRound="0:01" InPunchLateChangePoint="0:00" OutPunchLateInsideRound="0:01" OutPunchLateOutsideRound="0:01" OutPunchEarlyInsideGrace="0:00" OutPunchEarlyChangePoint="0:00" InPunchEarlyOutsideRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyOutsideGrace="0:00" UnscheduledOutRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyInsideRound="2:00"/>

<WSAPunchRoundRule OutPunchLateChangePoint="0:00" UnscheduledInGrace="0:00" OutPunchEarlyInsideRound="0:01" OutPunchEarlyOutsideGrace="0:00" Name="Ramadan" OutPunchEarlyOutsideRound="0:01" UseScheduledOut="false" InPunchLateInsideGrace="0:00" InPunchLateInsideRound="0:01" OutPunchLateOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchEarlyInsideGrace="0:00" UnscheduledInRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyChangePoint="2:00" InPunchLateOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchLateOutsideRound="0:01" OutPunchLateInsideGrace="0:00" IsMissedOutException="true" TransferGrace="0:00" UnscheduledOutGrace="0:00" TransferRound="0:01" InPunchLateChangePoint="0:00" OutPunchLateInsideRound="0:01" OutPunchLateOutsideRound="0:01" OutPunchEarlyInsideGrace="0:00" OutPunchEarlyChangePoint="0:00" InPunchEarlyOutsideRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyOutsideGrace="0:00" UnscheduledOutRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyInsideRound="2:00"/>

<WSAPunchRoundRule OutPunchLateChangePoint="0:00" UnscheduledInGrace="0:00" OutPunchEarlyInsideRound="0:01" OutPunchEarlyOutsideGrace="0:00" Name="Transfer Rounding" OutPunchEarlyOutsideRound="0:01" UseScheduledOut="true" InPunchLateInsideGrace="0:00" InPunchLateInsideRound="0:01" OutPunchLateOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchEarlyInsideGrace="0:00" UnscheduledInRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyChangePoint="2:00" InPunchLateOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchLateOutsideRound="0:01" OutPunchLateInsideGrace="0:00" IsMissedOutException="false" TransferGrace="0:00" UnscheduledOutGrace="0:00" TransferRound="0:01" InPunchLateChangePoint="0:00" OutPunchLateInsideRound="0:01" OutPunchLateOutsideRound="0:01" OutPunchEarlyInsideGrace="0:00" OutPunchEarlyChangePoint="0:00" InPunchEarlyOutsideRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyOutsideGrace="0:00" UnscheduledOutRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyInsideRound="2:00"/>

<WSAPunchRoundRule OutPunchLateChangePoint="0:00" UnscheduledInGrace="0:00" OutPunchEarlyInsideRound="0:01" OutPunchEarlyOutsideGrace="0:00" Name="Workrule Rounding" OutPunchEarlyOutsideRound="0:01" UseScheduledOut="false" InPunchLateInsideGrace="0:00" InPunchLateInsideRound="0:01" OutPunchLateOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchEarlyInsideGrace="0:00" UnscheduledInRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyChangePoint="2:00" InPunchLateOutsideGrace="0:00" InPunchLateOutsideRound="0:01" OutPunchLateInsideGrace="0:00" IsMissedOutException="true" TransferGrace="0:00" UnscheduledOutGrace="0:00" TransferRound="0:01" InPunchLateChangePoint="0:00" OutPunchLateInsideRound="0:01" OutPunchLateOutsideRound="0:01" OutPunchEarlyInsideGrace="0:00" OutPunchEarlyChangePoint="0:00" InPunchEarlyOutsideRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyOutsideGrace="0:00" UnscheduledOutRound="0:01" InPunchEarlyInsideRound="2:00"/>

</Response>

</Kronos_WFC>`
```

My Class looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Data;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

namespace Mojito.Models
{
    public class KronosPunchRoundRuleSummary
    {
        public List<KronosPunchRoundRule> kronosPunchRoundRules { get; set; }
    }

public class KronosPunchRoundRule
{
    public virtual int KronosPunchRoundRuleId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string OutPunchLateChangePoint { get; set; }
    public virtual string UnscheduledInGrace { get; set; }
    public virtual string OutPunchEarlyInsideRound { get; set; }
    public virtual string OutPunchEarlyOutsideGrace { get; set; }
    public virtual string OutPunchEarlyOutsideRound { get; set; }
    public virtual string UseScheduledOut { get; set; }
    public virtual string InPunchLateInsideGrace { get; set; }
    public virtual string InPunchLateInsideRound { get; set; }
    public virtual string OutPunchLateOutsideGrace { get; set; }
    public virtual string InPunchEarlyInsideGrace { get; set; }
    public virtual string UnscheduledInRound { get; set; }
    public virtual string InPunchEarlyChangePoint { get; set; }
    public virtual string InPunchLateOutsideGrace { get; set; }
    public virtual string InPunchLateOutsideRound { get; set; }
    public virtual string OutPunchLateInsideGrace { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsMissedOutException { get; set; }
    public virtual string TransferGrace { get; set; }
    public virtual string UnscheduledOutGrace { get; set; }
    public virtual string TransferRound { get; set; }
    public virtual string InPunchLateChangePoint { get; set; }
    public virtual string OutPunchLateInsideRound { get; set; }
    public virtual string OutPunchLateOutsideRound { get; set; }
    public virtual string OutPunchEarlyInsideGrace { get; set; }
    public virtual string OutPunchEarlyChangePoint { get; set; }
    public virtual string InPunchEarlyOutsideRound { get; set; }
    public virtual string InPunchEarlyOutsideGrace { get; set; }
    public virtual string UnscheduledOutRound { get; set; }
    public virtual string InPunchEarlyInsideRound { get; set; }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it I suggest you to read XML Serializer and Deserializer Tutorials.

- [XML Serialization and Deserialization: Part-1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part)
- [Serialize/Deserialize any object to an XML file](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/455861/Serialize-Deserialize-any-object-to-an-XML-file)

Hope helps. Greetings!

**UPDATE:**

#### To serialize a unknown object you must pass all object a add to the serializer to say hwo the must serialize:

```
public static void Save<T>(T item, string filename, IEnumerable<Type> typeList) where T : class, new()
    {

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), typeList.ToArray());

        // To write to a file, create a StreamWriter object.
        StreamWriter writer = null;

        try
        {
            writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
            var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, item, ns);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (writer != null)
                writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

#### To Deserialize unknown object its the same:

```
public static T Load<T>(string filename, IEnumerable<Type> typeList) where T : class, new()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filename))
            return new T();

        TextReader fileStream = null;
        try
        {
            // Construct an instance of the XmlSerializer with the type
            // of object that is being deserialized.

            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), typeList.ToArray());

            // To read the file, create a FileStream.
            fileStream = new StreamReader(filename);

            return xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream) as T;

            // Call the Deserialize method and cast to the object type.
            //  return xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream) as T;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new T();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fileStream != null)
                fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE2:**

**T** -> is the object you want to serialize.

**filname** -> the path/destinaton where you whant tu save it.

**IEnumerable** -> is a list of Types. Only declare a IEnumerable and Add all you type you will serialize there and after pass it on the Save, Load method.

Comment: I have already tried these tutorials - it is where I got most of the ideas from.  I just cannot seem to get it working

Comment: Maybe because you will deserialize a XML who you doesn't know which Type the are. Try the updated code.

Comment: Thank you this looks a lot closer to what I am actually trying to do, however it is a bit over my head.  I would like to try testing and debugging so I can get a clearer idea of what it is doing.  I seem to be stuck on how to call it and pass the string and iEnumerable.  The passing of the string seems straight forward but not sure i understand how to pass the Ienumerable

Comment: So this is what i have been trying but getting an error<br/>
    public ActionResult Test()
        {
            string fileName = @"c:\WSAPunchRoundRule.xml";
            KronosPunchRoundRuleSummary kprrs = new KronosPunchRoundRuleSummary();
            KronosPunchRoundRule.Load<KronosPunchRoundRule>(fileName,kprrs);
            return View();
        }' Error 4 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Mojito.Models.KronosPunchRoundRuleSummary' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Type>' Error

Comment: Because your KronosPunchRoundRule is a List<> and in the method is a IEnumerable<>. You can change List to IEnumerable, or IEnumerable to List. Or you can use the function of IEnumerbale "tolist"